# How to loop over the JSON object / list?

Tags: luatex, loops, json

I want to loop over `section` in the following JSON and print `name` the number of times it appears under section. How could I do this?

```
{
  "ID": "23",
  "section": [
      {
          "name": "A",
          "text": "This is the start of section",
          "subsection": [
            {
             name: "Sub section AA",
             text: " This is some text"
            },
            {
             name: "Sub section BB",
             text: " This is some text"
            }
          ]
      },
      {
          "name": "B", 
          "text": "This is the start of the section",
          "subsection": [
             {
               name: "Sub section EE",
               text: " This is some text"
             },
             {
               name: "Sub section DD",
               text: " This is some text"
            }
           ]
      }
  ]
}
```

Here is how I am reading and parsing the JSON:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{luacode}
% load json file
\begin{luacode}
    local json = require("json")
    local file = io.open("sample.json")
    tab = json.parse(file:read("*all"))
    file:close()
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}

The ID of the document is \directlua{tex.print(tab['ID'])}

Here is the list of all the sections:

\end{document}
```

`json.lua` file that parses the JSON ([Taken from answer by Henri Menke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489395/error-as-i-try-to-read-and-display-the-results-from-json-file/489397#489397)):

```
    local lpeg = assert(require("lpeg"))
local C, Cf, Cg, Ct, P, R, S, V =
    lpeg.C, lpeg.Cf, lpeg.Cg, lpeg.Ct, lpeg.P, lpeg.R, lpeg.S, lpeg.V

-- number parsing
local digit    = R"09"
local dot      = P"."
local eE       = S"eE"
local sign     = S"+-"^-1
local mantissa = digit^1 * dot * digit^0 + dot * digit^1 + digit^1
local exponent = (eE * sign * digit^1)^-1
local real     = sign * mantissa * exponent / tonumber

-- optional whitespace
local ws = S" \t\n\r"^0

-- match a literal string surrounded by whitespace
local lit = function(str)
    return ws * P(str) * ws
end

-- match a literal string and synthesize an attribute
local attr = function(str,attr)
    return ws * P(str) / function() return attr end * ws
end

-- JSON grammar
local json = P{
    "object",

    value =
        V"null_value" +
        V"bool_value" +
        V"string_value" +
        V"real_value" +
        V"array" +
        V"object",

    null_value =
        attr("null", nil),

    bool_value =
        attr("true", true) + attr("false", false),

    string_value =
        ws * P'"' * C((P'\\"' + 1 - P'"')^0) * P'"' * ws,

    real_value =
        ws * real * ws,

    array =
        lit"[" * Ct((V"value" * lit","^-1)^0) * lit"]",

    member_pair =
        Cg(V"string_value" * lit":" * V"value") * lit","^-1,

    object =
        lit"{" * Cf(Ct"" * V"member_pair"^0, rawset) * lit"}"
}

return { parse = function(str) return assert(json:match(str)) end }
```

**Update:**

I am trying to add dynamic sections / sub-sections using the for loop. For example,

```
\section{ A }
  This is the A section
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{ Some Sub Section }
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Another Sub Section}

\section{ B }
  This is the B section
\section{ C }
  This is the C section
```

Like sections and sub-sections, I will also dynamically generate tables from the JSON read.

Comment: you presumably just get a Lua table from the parse so the question is a pure Lua question about how to iterate over a table in Lua, that is not clearly on topic for this site

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Updated.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So there is no latex way to loop over the `tab`?

Comment: tex macros can not see Lua data at all, you need to copy the data from Lua to tex if you want to access it.

Comment: the question is far less clear after the edit, please make the input json match the required output. where do you expect the text and subsections to come from? You can only iterate over the lua table if you know its structure and that depends on the structure of the json that you have not shown.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Have updated the subsection part. The idea is that the JSON and latex here could be much more vast and complex. So would need a way, where I could see a generalisation, so adding more latex commands using the JSON does not appear to be a uphill task.

Comment: so there is no text in the json? all sections just have te stub text "this is section ...` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Updated yet again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just iterate over the returned Lua table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{luacode}
% load json file
\begin{luacode}
    local json = require("json")
    local file = io.open("sample.json")
    tab = json.parse(file:read("*all"))
    file:close()
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}

The ID of the document is \directlua{tex.print(tab['ID'])}

Here is the list of all the sections:
\directlua{
for i,k in ipairs(tab["section"]) do
 if (i>1) then
     tex.sprint (", ")
 end
     tex.sprint (k.name)
end
}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

The updated json was invalid, I assume this was intended:

```
{
    "ID": "23",
    "section": [
    {
            "name": "A",
            "text": "This is the start of section",
            "subsection": [
        {
            "name": "Sub section AA",
            "text": " This is some text"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sub section BB",
            "text": " This is some text"
        }
            ]
    },
      {
          "name": "B", 
          "text": "This is the start of the section",
          "subsection": [
              {
          "name": "Sub section EE",
          "text": " This is some text"
              },
              {
          "name": "Sub section DD",
                  "text": " This is some text"
              }
          ]
      }
    ]
}
```

So just change the Lua iterations to

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{luacode}
% load json file
\begin{luacode}
    local json = require("json")
    local file = io.open("sample.json")
    tab = json.parse(file:read("*all"))
    file:close()
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}

The ID of the document is \directlua{tex.print(tab['ID'])}

\chapter{zzz}

\directlua{
for i,k in ipairs(tab["section"]) do
     tex.print ("\string\\section{" .. k.name .. "}")
     tex.print (k.text)
  for ii,kk in ipairs(k["subsection"]) do
     tex.print ("\string\\subsection{" .. kk.name .. "}")
     tex.print (kk.text)
end
end
}
\end{document}
```

A more complete version would need to escape any tex-special characters and guard against empty fields.

Comment: I am trying to use `\section` command as `\section{tex.sprint (k.name)}` but looks like it does not work.

Comment: you could use `tex.print(\string\\section{k.name}` instead of tex.sprint (k.name) in the above loop, but a list of `\section` commands with no actual text does not produce good results as no page breaks are allowed @Amanda

Comment: Have also updated my question

Comment: @Amanda I  updated answer (last update:-)

Comment: So we are using `lua` to render `latex`. What purpose do the 2 dots `..` before and after json object serve?

Comment: @Amanda `..` is Lua string concatenation

Comment: Use `ipairs` instead of `pairs`.  The latter does not guarantee ordering for numerical indices.

Comment: Not related to this question but wanted to have your views. The real **JSON** is **huge**. It took around 32 seconds to generate a PDF of 2600 pages, when iterating over multiple points using lua. Do you think, there could be a better way to go from here in terms of time?

Comment: @Amanda  when I started to use tex, 15 minutes per page was quite common, so I still struggle to think of 32 seconds being a long time, impossible to say in general how to speed things up and whether the time is spent reading the json and building the lua table or in traversing the lua table or (most likely) in the tex  rendering the generated markup.

Comment: @HenriMenke ipairs done thanks (I knew that really:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay. Would you have any idea on how to save all the latex to a file which is ready to be rendered? I tried, appending all the latex to variable and saved that variable into the file. But when the file is read, it throws some `undefined controlled sequence error`

Comment: sorry already too many comments here, ask a new question with a new example if you need further help

Comment: @Amanda 32 seconds for 2600 pages sound pretty good.  Anyway, you can profile whether parsing JSON is the bottleneck using the `socket` library which also comes bundled with LuaTeX ([example code](https://termbin.com/ixd6)).  For the small JSON from the question I get `Time passed parsing JSON: 4.1961669921875e-05 s` in the log file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Have asked a separate question : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489722/saving-all-the-latex-to-a-file-and-then-render-reading-from-the-file?noredirect=1#comment1236607_489722

Comment: @HenriMenke For a 7MB JSON, I get 0.223 seconds. Time spent parsing is low and time spent parsing each section using lua is around `0.00043487548828125 s`. Why does it then take 32 seconds?

Comment: @Amanda typesetting 2600 pages may take a few seconds anyway just starting luatex  takes longer than your lua parse times, so the time is unrelated to any code you have shown, it all depends on how complicated the tex is, how big your fonts are (if you load some massive CJK font set it takes luatex a while to sort it out) whether your file searches are hashed using ls-r .....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there a way I could know the starting time of lualatex? I would be catering to multiple document generation requests, so wanted to understand this.

Comment: just time  `lualatex small2e`  to see how long it takes to typeset a trivial 1 page document (pdflatex sample2e is likely significantly quicker)